# Regex to find 4 consecutive characters or numbers

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a situation where I need a regex to find 4 consecutive numbers or strings

For example.

John12 - True (because it contains 4 consecutive characters)
M1593a - True (because it contains 4 consecutive letters)
La349a - False (because it fails to satisfy both)

How can we solve this?

Comment: You may want to try this `[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4}`

Comment: Excellect revo!. It worked. Thanks for your quich reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to complicate things. Consider both conditions in an alternation:

```
[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4}
```

Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
if (m.find())
    // Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

`/[\d]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4}/g` works in javascript for that, unsure how you want to start/end your regex in java though

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regular expression that you need

```
\d{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4}
```

I tested it on all of the examples you gave in your question and it worked just as you asked for .
Happy to help.